# Using woocommerce_calculate_totals hook to set "Local pickup" shipping cost to 0

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

We have modified the checkout process in Woocommerce to allow the customer to select between delivery or store pickup.

I'm using the **woocommerce_calculate_totals** to check which method was selected by the customer and if the user selected store pick up I want to set the shipping fee to 0

I'm using the following code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', function($order) {
    /* 
     * We need to check if the user selected local delivery, which would be added to the request string 
     * If no store pick-up is selected, then we don't need to display shipping calculations
     */ 
    global $woocommerce;

    if(!empty($_POST['post_data'])) {
        if(strpos($_POST['post_data'], 'local-delivery')) {

        } else {
            $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total = 0.00;
            $woocommerce->cart->shipping_tax_total = 0.00; 
        } 
    }
}, 40, 1);
```

If a user selects local delivery, it calculates shipping costs. However, if a user switches back to pick up, Woocommerce does not remove the shipping cost.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

**You don't need any code for that**… It can be done through WooCommerce settings. So you will have 2 shipping methods in your shipping settings for a shipping Zone:

- A "Flat rate" shipping method for "Local delivery" (with a cost)
- A "Local pickup" shipping method for "Store pick up" (without cost)

For the "Store pick up" ("Local pickup" shipping method):

[image]

You will set **a cost of 0**:

[image]

Then you will get in cart and checkout something like:

[image]